# Identifying a Diode

Tags: diodes, identification, components

I am trying to work out what diode this is. I can tell that the red spot indicates the cathode. If I use the standard color scheme for resistors I get 0904 (or 904 if the first black band is not counted per https://www.tpub.com/neets/book7/24k.htm).

Searching for 1N0904 doesn't turn up anything however 1N904 does.

So is this a 1N904? If not, what is it?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Wow, that thing's ancient!

Comment: Early 1970s board I am helping to reverse engineer..

Comment: Can you measure a forward voltage on it?

Comment: I’d think that the stripe would indicate the cathode, and the red dot would be the anode, but you could easily verify with a DMM.

Comment: @JohnD - yes, already did.

Comment: @Hearth - 0.6V measured

Comment: I think the best thing for this is to continue reverse-engineering under the assumption this is a 1N904 (a basic signal diode that's been obsolete for ages), and see if the circuit you end up with makes sense. If it doesn't, chances are it may be a zener diode of some sort. With that forward voltage it's definitely a silicon pn diode.